Replace substring in SQL Teradata not working
I'm trying to replace/remove +-signs in all occurences in a variable:
"SELECT   REPLACE('+123', '+', '') as test
FROM     NL.KUB_kvitteringer"

This gives me the following error:
Error during Prepare
 37000(-3706)[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-3706)Syntax error: expected something between the 'SELECT' keyword and the 'REPLACE' keyword. (0,00 secs)

I can't understand why the code doesn't work.

As REPLACE is a keyword in Teradata (e.g. REPLACE VIEW), the function is named OReplace (similar for OTranslate)

Here are the correct statement:
SELECT OREPLACE('+123', '+', '') AS test
FROM NL.KUB_kvitteringer;

Use OREPLACE function instead of REPLACE.
